# Insert text at varying places into a string

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, vba

How do I insert specific text into varying places in a string? It is to add details to addresses that are missing.

I'm aware I can use the `LEFT` and the `MID` functions to do this, but when the address data varies in length it fails, however it always has to come after "Faketown" in my example.

For example:

Cell `A1` may contain

> 123 Fake St, Faketown, AB1 2CD

Cell `A2` may contain

> 12 TotalFake St, FakeTown, EF3 4GH

I'd like a formula/macro for the column next to it to show:

Cell `B1`

> 123 Fake St, Faketown, Fakecounty, AB1 2CD

Cell `B2`

> 12 TotalFake St, FakeTown, Fakecounty, EF3 4GH

As you can see it's the addition of "FakeCounty" in the format above that is required. The formula/macro should always put "Fakecounty" after "FakeTown" regardless of how many characters precede FakeTown (otherwise the 'LEFT' and 'MID' functions would be perfect).

I'm certain it's possible, but can anyone point me in the direction I need to go/provide a formula/code that can achieve this?

Comment: As a Formula? Or are you using VBA?

Comment: I can use either, preferably formula if its possible.

Comment: Where is the fakecountry name coming from? Is it constant or change?

Comment: fakecounty would always be the same.

Comment: Take a look at the InStr and InStrRev functions, they will return the integer position of a given character or characters.
Fx you'd be able to do InStrRev and look for the first occurence of a "," , then you can combine those with the Left and Mid and Right functions.